# Ajax success does not display message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

my ajax success:function is not work.When i have successfully uploaded file,it should dispay message.However,it does not display message eventhough the file has been successfully uploaded.Can somone help me fix this problem?

Here is my code;

```
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $(".progress-bar").width('0%');
            },
            error:function(){
                $('#uploadStatus').html('<p style="color:#EA4335;">File upload failed, please try again.</p>');
            },
            success: function(resp){
                if(resp == 'ok'){
                    $('#uploadForm')[0].reset();
                    $('#uploadStatus').html('<p style="color:#28A74B;">File has uploaded successfully!</p>');
                    console.log('it works');
                }else if(resp == 'err'){
                    $('#uploadStatus').html('<p style="color:#EA4335;">Please select a valid file to upload.</p>');
                }
            }
```

php code:

```
$upload = 'err'; 
if(!empty($_FILES['file'])){ 
    $targetDir = "D:/MMHE4DFiles/"; 
    $allowTypes = array('avi'); 
    $path=$_POST['path'];
    $fileName = basename($_FILES['file']['name']); 
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir.$path.".avi";//$fileName; 

    // Check whether file type is valid 
    $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){ 
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetFilePath);

        }

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetFilePath)){
        $upload = 'ok';
        echo $upload;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check what does `resp` has in it ?

Comment: Please post your upload.php too

Comment: Done share,upload.php

Comment: It seems that your code is not reaching `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetFilePath)){}` here.  Try to echo in every else condtion to debug the issue

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work.

Reason:
You move the file twice. But after the first move it is gone, so the second move must fail.

Solution:

```
// Check whether file type is valid 
    $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 

    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){ 
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetFilePath) )
{
echo "ok";  
exit();} 

       }
echo "err";
```

(Delete your last paragraph.  )

Comment: It does show the success message now after deleteting the last paragraph.However it does not show the error message if i attache the invalid format of the file.Any thought sir to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the code. Now it returns the error if empty or wrong file type.

Comment: If the answer helped you please upvote it and mark it as accepted.